# how can i redirect to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have added 3 **slider plugins**,1 **menu plugin** and **login form** in home page, but when I m trying to login to page, that is showing the same page and not going to the next page. 
Pls give me solution.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this client side or server side?

Comment: Can you show us any code from you login script?

Comment: <div class="pg">
               
                            <font size="4" face="Pristina" font-size="7" color="lavenderblush" font-weight= "bolder">UserName&nbsp;</font> <input type="text" name="t3"> 
                            <br><font size="4" face="Pristina" font-size="x-large" color="lavenderblush" font-weight= "bolder">  Password</font>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password" name="p1">
                           <input type="submit" name="l1" value="Login" >
                            
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Embed your input elements and submit button inside `<form> <\form>` tags .

So that your input elements will be available in the server side .